# Build and Deploy in jbpm 6.2 gives org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnauthorizedException

Tags: jboss, jbpm

Am trying to Build and Deploy the sample project "bpms-project" which comes with the installation of JBPM which goes UnauthorizedException, am using the admin user to build and deploy, am not sure am i missing something.Here is the exception

```
08:07:04,152 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.i18n] (http-127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8080-5) RESTEASY006050: Found BeanManager at java:comp/BeanManager
08:07:04,528 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (http-127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8080-5) RESTEASY000100: Failed executing POST deployment/org.jboss.quickstarts.brms:bpms_project:1.0.0/deploy: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnauthorizedExceptio
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor.preProcess(SecurityInterceptor.java:68) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:252) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContextFilter.doFilter(DynamicJaxbContextFilter.java:63) [kie-remote-services-6.3.0.Final-redhat-5.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.BasicAuthSecurityFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthSecurityFilter.java:53) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.7.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:0.7.4.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecureHeadersFilter.java:53) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.7.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:0.7.4.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SecurityIntegrationFilter.java:45) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.7.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:0.7.4.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:400) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to build and deploy trough the rest interface using a POST, am i correct? Then make sure that the admin user has the rights to do this. Look in EAP/standalone/configuration/application-roles.properties and make sure this line is there: **bpmsAdmin=admin, rest-all**

The important part is rest-all!

Dont forget to restart bpm when you have made configuration changes or reload the configuration using

```
bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:reload
```

Another way to build would be trough the web-gui and then you should not need this.